# Disable year for JQueryUI DatePicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to disable years from my "YearPicker?", it's a DatePicker where you're only able to pick years. I need to disable all years and enable only a range of years (From 2012 to now, for example).

I'm using the JQueryUI DatePicker and it looks like this:

[image]

**CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
   <style>
        .ui-datepicker-calendar {
            display: none;
        }        
    </style>
```

**JS:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            viewMode: 2,
            format: 'yyyy',
            maxDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31),
            minDate: new Date(2012, 0, 1)
        });
    })
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<label>Year: <input class="form-control" type="text" id="datepicker"></label>
```

Comment: Something does not add up here. I think you are using an alternate date picker, and not the jQuery UI Datepicker. `viewMode` and `format` are not a option of jQuery UI Datepicker. Please see: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I've made a mistake, I thought that I were using jQueryUI datepicker but I were using Bootstrap DatePicker. I have both imported, but the app is taking first the Bootstrap one. Sorry for the misunderstanding and thanks for help, I saw the error thanks to this comment.

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to identify the issue. I did post a suggestion, something to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I was importing Bootstrap DatePicker and JQueryUI DatePicker, I thought that I was using the second one only, but the app was detecting only the first one, my code now is like this and working:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
                    minViewMode: 2,
                    format: 'yyyy',
                    startDate: '2012',
                    endDate: 'y'
                });
```

Thanks all for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can make what you're doing work, yet I think it's a bit more work than is needed. I would suggest maybe consider using Autocomplete instead. Take a look:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var today = new Date();
      var min = today.getFullYear() - 6;
      // Adjust above as needed, currently 6 years before this year
      var results = [];
      for (min; min <= today.getFullYear(); min++) {
        results.push(min.toString());
      }
      resp(results)
    }
  }).focus(function(e) {
    $(e.target).autocomplete("search", "");
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label>Year: <input class="form-control" type="text" id="datepicker" data-years="6"></label>
```

Can move this to it's own function if needed too.

```
var function makeYearList(n){
  var today = new Date();
  var min = today.getFullYear() - n;
  var results = [];
  for (min; min <= today.getFullYear(); min++) {
    results.push(min.toString());
  }
  return results;
}
```

You can also adjust the theming to list them horizontally versus vertically.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify simple strings as well to achieve the desired formatting:

```js
{
    format: 'MM/yyyy',
    startDate: '01/2022',
    endDate: '12/2022',
}
```